# Which method should I use to change the size of a Gui?

Tags: lua, roblox

when attempting to make the size of the y axis smaller using scale for a frame in my Gui, it would come up with an error message, which should I use?

```
-- method #1 (using vector2.new)
frame.Size = Vector.new("0.33, 0, 0.1125, 0") -- with quotes and brackets
frame.Size = Vector2.new{0.33, 0},{0.2, 0} -- with no quotes and 2 sets of table brackets
frame.Size = Vector2.new{0.33, 0, 0.2, 0} -- with no quotes and 1 set of table brackets
-- method #2 (not using Vector2.new)
frame.Size = ("0.33, 0, 0.2, 0") -- using quotes and table brackets
frame.Size = {0.33, 0},{0.2, 0} -- using 2 sets of table brackets
frame.Size = {0.33, 0, 0.2, 0} -- using 1 set of table brackets
```

please help, thanks!

Comment: What does the error message say? Anyway, I don't thing that `frame.Size = Vector2.new{0.33, 0},{0.2, 0}` and `frame.Size = {0.33, 0},{0.2, 0}` are going to work.

Comment: all the error message says is "expected, got Vector2) "

Comment: It seems that you need `UDim2`: `frame.Size = UDim2.new(0.33, 0, 0.2, 0)`.

Comment: thank you, I will try it now

Comment: Then please accept as an answer.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It seems that you need `UDim2`: `frame.Size = UDim2.new(0.33, 0, 0.2, 0)`. See https://coderoad.ru/55194706/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%82-%D1%81%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%B2-Roblox-Lua, e.g.

Comment: Why not link to the official documentation for UDim2? https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/datatype/UDim2

Answer (score 0):

You should honestly use Roblox Studio to make your Gui. This will allow you to drag and drop, scale, and edit your Gui to any way you want. Then use a plugin for studio called gui to lua(https://www.roblox.com/library/1343400903/Gui-to-Lua-Converter-Revamped) this is one.

I made a video on this if interested. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MOTCPETRegM&t=1s

If you insist on manually doing it you will need one or 2 things

frame.Position = UDim2.new(0,0,0,0)

frame.Size = UDim2.new(0,0,0,0)
where the values are (xScale,xOffset,yScale,yOffset)

Something to keep in mind the scale is on a scale of 1-0. 1 being full 0 being none.